# Why does TakeLast<T>() method not work on a ReplaySubject<T>

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

According the the MSDN documentation, the following code should output '5' to the console window.  Instead, nothing is displayed.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var o = new ReplaySubject<int>();

     o.OnNext(0);
     o.OnNext(1);
     o.OnNext(2);
     o.OnNext(3);
     o.OnNext(4);
     o.OnNext(5);

     o.TakeLast(1).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

     Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Expected output:

```
5
Press any key to exit
```

Actual output:

```
Press any key to exit
```

Can anyone please explain why this is the case?

Comment: There is no `TakeLast` in the .NET framework. Please share a link to that MSDN documentation page you are referring to.

Comment: @Daniel, it's part of the Reactive Extensions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212114%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you never notify the completion of the sequence, so `TakeLast` doesn't know the sequence is complete and continues to wait for the end of the sequence. This works as expected:

```
var o = new ReplaySubject<int>();

o.OnNext(0);
o.OnNext(1);
o.OnNext(2);
o.OnNext(3);
o.OnNext(4);
o.OnNext(5);
o.OnCompleted();

o.TakeLast(1).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! My follow-up question is how do I accomplish grabbing the latest value without calling OnComplete(). Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762163/how-to-get-the-latest-value-from-a-replaysubjectt-before-completion) in case you know the answer.