# How to get the latest value from a ReplaySubject<T> before completion

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I need a way of grabbing the most recent item added to a ReplaySubject that matches certain criteria. The sample code below does what I need it to do but it doesn't feel like the correct approach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var o = new ReplaySubject<string>();

    o.OnNext("blueberry");
    o.OnNext("chimpanzee");
    o.OnNext("abacus");
    o.OnNext("banana");
    o.OnNext("apple");
    o.OnNext("cheese");

    var latest = o.Where(i => i.StartsWith("b"))
        .Latest().First();

    Console.WriteLine(latest);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```
banana
Press any key to exit
```

Initially, I tried using `.Where().TakeLast(1)`; however, I now know from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760212/why-does-takelastt-method-not-work-on-a-replaysubjectt) that you must call `OnComplete()` on the subject before `TakeLast()` will return anything. Calling `OnComplete()` is not an option for me because I need to keep this stream open.

Can anyone please validate whether this is the most effective approach to what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks!

*EDIT*

Please note that I'm using Reactive Extensions and IEnumerable code samples will not work.

**UPDATE**

I'm leaning towards the following code because I believe it is non-blocking unless anyone can tell me differently:

```
var latest = o.Where(i => i.StartsWith("b")).Replay(1);

using (latest.Connect())
     latest.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: Read this? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/rx/thread/d460ae46-8fe4-43dd-b149-b928efa03df4

Comment: @kevin: I'm sorry, I may be missing something but I don't see how the link you posted is relevant to my situation.

Comment: Basically I found some posts with 'similar' problems (getting the 'last' item). That one shows you have to go back 2 items... another maybe helpful one here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/rx/thread/af09d22a-233b-4ac7-9c7e-cd1f581e5f60  But I'm over my head so I'll stop now. 3 strikes! :)

Comment: Bear in mind that with the UPDATE solution, any subscription that happens *before* you call Connect will return 'blueberry' as the first value and 'banana' as the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using `BehaviorSubject<string>`. The drawback is that you have to subscribe at the beginning but that is probably what you want to do anyway. This should provide you with isolation you need.

```
var o = new ReplaySubject<string>();
var bs = new BehaviorSubject<string>(default(string));
o.Where(i => i.StartsWith("b")).Subscribe(bs);

o.OnNext("blueberry"); Console.WriteLine(bs.First());
o.OnNext("chimpanzee"); Console.WriteLine(bs.First());
o.OnNext("abacus"); Console.WriteLine(bs.First());
o.OnNext("banana"); Console.WriteLine(bs.First());
o.OnNext("apple"); Console.WriteLine(bs.First());
o.OnNext("cheese"); Console.WriteLine(bs.First());
```

Output:

```
blueberry
blueberry
blueberry
banana
banana
banana
```

Comment: I knew that I could achieve this using a BehaviorSubject but the underlying stream needed to remain a ReplaySubject for other reasons. It didn't even occur to me to create a BehaviorSubject and subscribe to the underlying ReplaySubject. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So long as your happy using these blocking operators (which it looks like you are) I'd look into using the MostRecent operator.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var o = new ReplaySubject<string>();

    o.OnNext("blueberry");
    o.OnNext("chimpanzee");
    o.OnNext("abacus");
    o.OnNext("banana");
    o.OnNext("apple");
    o.OnNext("cheese");

    var latest = o.Where(i => i.StartsWith("b"))
        .MostRecent("SomeDefaultValue")
        .First();

    Console.WriteLine(latest);

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I've posted a revision to my original question with provides a non-blocking way of accomplishing this. I based it on your original post which you so quickly removed ;)

Comment: @Matthew Glace - Yeah I removed it because I wasn't happy with the different results depending on where you connected (either before or after the subscription). Not sure if there's any other way round that at this point but didn't want to post something that I wasn't happy with ;)